# deploy an ActiveX Component as msi or cab?

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, windows-installer, cab

I'm trying to deploy my dll (just a dll that needs to be registerd, nothing else) but cannot figure out the best way to do it.

A CA signed cab seems to be the nicer way to do it, since it doesn't seem like a full program to the user and he only gets one prompt, but I'm facing the following problem:

- the cab is downloaded, then the yellow bar appears. I would like to tell the user something like "simply click allow up here", but how do i know that the yellow bar is already being shown or if the cab is still being downloaded? Can i check if it's displayed with javascript somehow?

The problem I'm facing with an MSI is that after installing the dll and registering it, the user still gets the yellow bar and has to accept the component for this website, but i don't understand why this doesn't happen, when i install the add-on from cooliris.com or quakelive.com - i install their MSI and that's that. How can i achieve that with an MSI? And why do they use an MSI instead of a cab?

By the way, my dll is just used for one website.

Comment: found a 'way' to figure out when the information band is showing. Simply check the document.body.offsetHeight with a timer:

var h1= document.body.offsetHeight;
create ActiveXObject or do something to show the information bar
var h2 = document.body.offsetHeight;
if( h2 < h1 ) { // bar is there} else { // nothing }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access Information Band state from Javascript, but you can try to instantiate your control inside a try block, and if you catch an exception *assume* the Information Band is showing, and display something like "If the control isn't loading, click this yellow band."  And consider adding a "Click here for more help" link.

I think that's the best you can do.

And as to your original question: yes, I would shoot for a .cab unless you absolutely need an .msi.

Good luck.